# css position attribute not working in chrome 29

Tags: css, google-chrome

i am facing a problem with new version of chrome 29.
i set the css of a div as this

```
    .dijitBorderContainerPane, .dijitBorderContainerNoGutterPane {
     position: absolute !important;
     z-index: 2;
     }
```

it is working correctly on firefox IE and chrome 25 to 28.
but not showing correctly on chrome 29.

please help me out.

Comment: @Ahsan incomplete question dont know what you want to achieve, i suggest create demo on http://jsfiddle.net and tell where you want to position that element. hope i will be able to help you

Comment: Seems to work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/Ty4MN/

Answer (score 1):

Use the browsers `html/css inspector` to check if the style were added correctly. And check if nothing else override your settings.

Answer (score 1):

At first use inspect element to see what styles has been used for your element
Another hint is that when you are using absolute value for position attribute you should set the position (left,top,right,bottom) parameters, without these you won't gain result. as below:

```
.dijitBorderContainerPane, .dijitBorderContainerNoGutterPane {
 top: 12;
 left: 20;
 position: absolute !important;
 z-index: 2;
 }
```

it was just an example

Comment: It is occasionally desirable to use absolute positioning without wishing to specify an X or Y value.